# Postgres DISTINCT query running slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of products that I'm trying to fetch the most recent price for each particular item. Came up with the following query, but I feel like it is incredibly slow for how simple it is. The table has 32,000 record and this is taking 908ms to complete. Feel like I'm missing something simple.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (itemsPrices.id) itemsPrices.id,
    itemsPrices.price
   FROM itemsPrices
  ORDER BY itemsPrices.id, itemsPrices.timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Last than one second to process 32k records isn't so bad.

However, you might be able to speed it up with an index on `itemsPrices(id, timestamp desc, price)`.